# Importing meshes from other *.Blend files

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, blend-files

I have found lots of solutions for importing meshes from other files in Blender. I have used this method from the official documentation:

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html?highlight=blenddatalibraries

The problem in this is when you import a mesh from a file it will create a new scene automatically. I want to add all the meshes and objects in one object and change their names as soon as it is imported. Are there any methods that could merge scenes together from Python?

Best,
Mahmoud